# My fiancé is British and am from the Caribbean

Tags: marriage, uk-citizenship

My fiancé and I are planning to get married in my Caribbean country but would want to reside in his uk home what is the procedure needed

Comment: Where exactly from the Caribbean are you from?

Comment: Are you just looking to reside in the UK or do you wish to obtain UK citizenship?